Proving a 2D Submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^4$
Problem: Show that the set
$$ M := \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus \{0\} : x_1 x_3 - x_2^2 = 0, \, x_2 x_4 - x_3^2 = 0, \, x_1 x_4 - x_2 x_3 = 0 \} $$
is a differentiable submanifold of $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ with dimension $ 2 $.
Attempt: I am struggling with setting up a continuously differentiable function to prove this statement. Specifically, I am trying to find an appropriate function
$$ F: U \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $$
for some open neighborhood $ U $ of each $ m \in M $, such that the rank of the Jacobian of $ F $ is 2 for all points in $ M $.
Could someone guide me on how to construct this function and proceed with the proof?
Thank you!

@Ceru I thought the function $F$ should go from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. Isn't that right?

First notice that
$$x_1 x_4 = x_2 x_3 \Longleftrightarrow x_1 x_3 x_4 = x_2 x_3^2 \Longleftrightarrow x_1 x_3 x_4 = x_2^2 x_4 \Longleftrightarrow x_1 x_3 =x_2^2$$
It means that one of those two conditions is redundant so you can remove one. We'll remove the condition $x_1 x_4 = x_2 x_3$ for example.
We define the function of class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{rcl}
   \phi \quad : \quad U =\mathbb{R}^4 ~ \backslash ~ \left( \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup S_{x_1,0} \cup S_{x_4,0} \right) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}^2 \\
   (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) & \longmapsto & \left( x_1 x_3 -x_2^2, x_2 x_4 -x_3^2 \right)
  \end{array} 
\end{align}
where
$$S_{x_1,0}=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^4~ \backslash ~ \lbrace 0 \rbrace ~ | ~ x_1 \neq 0, x_2=x_3=x_4=0 \rbrace$$ and $$S_{x_4,0}=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^4~ \backslash ~ \lbrace 0 \rbrace ~ | ~ x_1=x_2=x_3=0, x_4 \neq 0 \rbrace$$.
It follows that $\phi^{-1} ( \lbrace 0 \rbrace )=M \cap U$. The jacobian matrix of $\phi$ for any element of $U$ is
$$
\text{Jac} ~ \phi =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_3 & -2x_2 & x_1 & 0 \\
0 & x_4 & -2x_3 & x_2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It suffices to show that the rank of the jacobian is $\geqslant 2,~\forall x \in U$. We have

$\text{rank Jac} ~ \phi = 0$ iff $x=0$.
$\text{rank Jac} ~ \phi = 1$ iff $x \in S_{x_1,0} \cup S_{x_4,0}$
$\text{rank Jac} ~ \phi \geqslant 2$ for all the other cases.

This shows that the differential is surjective for any $x \in U$. We now need to construct two functions $\varphi : V \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\psi : W \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, both of class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and such that
$$\varphi^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)=M \cap V, \quad \forall x \in S_{x_1,0} ~ : ~\text{$V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$}$$
and
$$ \psi^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)=M \cap W, \quad \forall x \in S_{x_4,0} ~ : ~\text{$W$ is an open neighborhood of $x$}$$
that need to verify $\text{rank Jac} ~ \varphi \geqslant 2$ and $\text{rank Jac} ~ \psi \geqslant 2$.
I haven't found the pairs $(\varphi , V)$ and $(\psi , W)$ yet. Hopefully this is still useful to you. I'm wondering if using the other caracterizations of real submanifolds wouldn't be better.
